# Diplaying widgets causes responsive slider to not show up

Tags: widgets

I'm making a custom home page template. On the top I have an image **slider(using the Responsive slider plugin)**. Than I query some posts and after that I want to include one of my widgets.

The problem is if I add the get_sidebar() call or display just one single widget(using Widget Instance plugin's shortcode), the slider is gone. I mean it does not get loaded.

The entire page loads ok, javascript works, jquery works.. everything works except the slider.

If any more info is needed, just comment and I'll add.

Comment: Which Plugin is this exactly? Is this site online somewhere? Please Show some code.

Comment: the plugins used are: Responsive slider and Widget Instance. I fixed this by copying the outputed widget html (it's a text widget), and paste that html into page template...not really a solution.. :(